# How to transform XML structure to SQL columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm working with SQL Server 2005.

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
<Item Type="Menu" Name="File">
    <Item Type="Selectable" Id="Open"/>
    <Item Type="Selectable" Id="Close"/>
    <Item Type="Menu" Name="Export"/>
         <Item Type="Selectable" Id="As JPEG"/>
         ....
    and so on, with N-level of menus
```

How can I translate this into a SQL table with columns:

Selectable, Level1Menu, Level2Menu, Level3Menu

where Open and Close would have File as level1Menu and NULL for all the Menu columns,
but As JPEG would have File and Export as level1Menu and level2Menu and NULL otherwise.

Thanks.

Comment: I would seriously think about reviewing your table structure as a multicolumn definition as you're implying would be a nightmare to maintain. As the link in the Rubens Faria's answer points out, you'd be better off with an hierarchical table, i.e. a self-referencing table, than a multicolumn like this.

Comment: @Paulo - I appreciate your concern, so how would I translate the above XML into a self-referencing table with just two columns? - I think I need to take my XML and perform the inverse operation of what Ruben's answer shows.  At that point it becomes trivial to self-join to the table and generate what I'm originally looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look here: [SQL Server 2005: Recursive Hierarchies to XML - CTEs vs. UDF](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/christianwade/archive/2004/11/09/234.aspx)